# How does this operator '??' work in php code.?

Tags: php, php-7

```
$array = ['name'=>'Jonh', 'lastname' => 'Doe', 'nickname' => 'JD'] ;

$person = $array['name'] ?? null ; //try to change  null to true or false<br>
    echo $person;

$person = $array['age'] ?? null;  //no Undefined index: age<br>
    echo $person;
```

I can't find  any documentation about it.

Comment: Its same as ternary

Answer (score 8):

It's new [PHP7 "null coalescing operator"](http://php.net/manual/ru/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op):

```
// Fetches the value of $_GET['user'] and returns 'nobody'
// if it does not exist.
$username = $_GET['user'] ?? 'nobody';
// This is equivalent to:
$username = isset($_GET['user']) ? $_GET['user'] : 'nobody';
```

**While**

short form of [Ternary Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) `?:` does nearly the same for years (as of at least PHP 5.3)

Comment: It appears to also work in php 5.6.19 for some reason.

Comment: @TimBrownlaw not in 5.1.18 though :(

Comment: Thanks everyone for all of the helpful answers to my questions!

Answer (score 2):

You can find doc about it in php.net [here](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op).

**EDIT:**

It works like combination of `isset()` and `?`
So code like:

```
return isset($a)?$a:$b
```

could be something like:

```
return $a??$b
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a null coalescing operator- Please refer to [this link](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op)